# Handling CSV in SQLite Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv, upload

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd, csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("CleanData.db")
cur = con.cursor()

a_file = open("csv1.csv")
rows = csv.reader(a_file)

cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO EmpMaster(OID, Month, Year, EMP_CODE, LocationCode, FullName, DateOfPay, PaidDays, Basic, BasicArr, HRA, HRAArr, EducationAllowance, EducationAllowanceArr, PDA, PDAArr, FoodAllowance, FoodAllowanceArr, GrossPM, LTA, LTAArr, LeaveEncashment, OtherEarning, CarReimbursement, CarReimbursementArr, AttireReimbursement, AttireReimbursementArr, TelephoneReimbursement, TelephoneReimbursementArr, BooksandPeriodicals, BooksandPeriodicalsArr, GiftAllowance, GiftAllowanceArr, GadgetReimbursement, GadgetReimbursementArr, HomeComfortAllowance, TotalEarnings, PF, VPF, PFArr, ESIC, PT, TDS, Loan, LWF, FoodDeduction, GiftCoupon, TotalDeductions, NetSalary, Gender, Designation, Department, FatherOrHusbandName, CurrentAddress, PermanenetAddress, DOB, DOJ, DOL, PANNo, UANNo, PFAccNo, ESICNo, AdharNum, Mobilenumber, Bank, BankAccNo, IFSCCode, natureofwork, hrsofwrkfrom, hrsofwrkto, intervalfrom, intervalto, totalhrs, totalint, EmployeeStatus, woff, Dateswithmonthandyearonwhichsheislaidoffandnotemployed, Totaldaysemployedintheorganisation, Dateonwhichwomangivespaymentperiod, Noticeundersection6oftheMaternityBenefitAct1961, Dateofbirthofchild, Dateofproductionofproofofpregnancyundersection6oftheMaternityBenefitAct1961, Dateofproductionofproofofdeliveryormiscarriageordeath, Wherethematernitybenefitdeliverythedateonwhichispaidinadvancebeforeitispaidandtheamountthereof, Dateonwhichsubsequentpaymentofmaternitybenefitismadeandtheamountthereof, Wherethemedicalbonusispaidthedateonwhichitispaidandtheamountthereof, Dateonwhichwagesonaccountofleavearepaidandamountthereof, Nameofthepersonnominatedbythewoman, IfthewomandiesthedateofherdeaththenameofthepersontowhomaternitybenefitandORorotheramountwaspaidtheamountthereofandthedateofpayment, Ifthewomandiesandthechildsurvivesthenameofthepersontowhomtheamountofmaternitybenefitwaspaidonbehalfofthechildandtheperiodforwhichitwaspaid, Dat1, Dat2, Dat3, Dat4, Dat5, Dat6, Dat7, Dat8, Dat9, Dat10, Dat11, Dat12, Dat13, Dat14, Dat15, Dat16, Dat17, Dat18, Dat19, Dat20, Dat21, Dat22, Dat23, Dat24, Dat25, Dat26, Dat27, Dat28, Dat29, Dat30, Dat31) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", rows)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp")
print(cur.fetchall())

con.commit()
con.close()
```

I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kmc487\Desktop\prog\PWHPythonCoors\simplecode.py", line 12, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: 122 values for 121 columns
```

After reducing number of values as shown below:

```
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO EmpMaster(OID, Month, Year, EMP_CODE, LocationCode, FullName, DateOfPay, PaidDays, Basic, BasicArr, HRA, HRAArr, EducationAllowance, EducationAllowanceArr, PDA, PDAArr, FoodAllowance, FoodAllowanceArr, GrossPM, LTA, LTAArr, LeaveEncashment, OtherEarning, CarReimbursement, CarReimbursementArr, AttireReimbursement, AttireReimbursementArr, TelephoneReimbursement, TelephoneReimbursementArr, BooksandPeriodicals, BooksandPeriodicalsArr, GiftAllowance, GiftAllowanceArr, GadgetReimbursement, GadgetReimbursementArr, HomeComfortAllowance, TotalEarnings, PF, VPF, PFArr, ESIC, PT, TDS, Loan, LWF, FoodDeduction, GiftCoupon, TotalDeductions, NetSalary, Gender, Designation, Department, FatherOrHusbandName, CurrentAddress, PermanenetAddress, DOB, DOJ, DOL, PANNo, UANNo, PFAccNo, ESICNo, AdharNum, Mobilenumber, Bank, BankAccNo, IFSCCode, natureofwork, hrsofwrkfrom, hrsofwrkto, intervalfrom, intervalto, totalhrs, totalint, EmployeeStatus, woff, Dateswithmonthandyearonwhichsheislaidoffandnotemployed, Totaldaysemployedintheorganisation, Dateonwhichwomangivespaymentperiod, Noticeundersection6oftheMaternityBenefitAct1961, Dateofbirthofchild, Dateofproductionofproofofpregnancyundersection6oftheMaternityBenefitAct1961, Dateofproductionofproofofdeliveryormiscarriageordeath, Wherethematernitybenefitdeliverythedateonwhichispaidinadvancebeforeitispaidandtheamountthereof, Dateonwhichsubsequentpaymentofmaternitybenefitismadeandtheamountthereof, Wherethemedicalbonusispaidthedateonwhichitispaidandtheamountthereof, Dateonwhichwagesonaccountofleavearepaidandamountthereof, Nameofthepersonnominatedbythewoman, IfthewomandiesthedateofherdeaththenameofthepersontowhomaternitybenefitandORorotheramountwaspaidtheamountthereofandthedateofpayment, Ifthewomandiesandthechildsurvivesthenameofthepersontowhomtheamountofmaternitybenefitwaspaidonbehalfofthechildandtheperiodforwhichitwaspaid, Dat1, Dat2, Dat3, Dat4, Dat5, Dat6, Dat7, Dat8, Dat9, Dat10, Dat11, Dat12, Dat13, Dat14, Dat15, Dat16, Dat17, Dat18, Dat19, Dat20, Dat21, Dat22, Dat23, Dat24, Dat25, Dat26, Dat27, Dat28, Dat29, Dat30, Dat31) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", rows)
```

This error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kmc487\Desktop\prog\PWHPythonCoors\simplecode.py", line 9, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 121, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Kindly help..

Answer (score 0):

The first error indicates there were too many (122) placeholder ? in the executemany. The second error indicates that the imported csv has 2 columns. The posted code likely did not produce both errors because the line numbers are different. The two posted executemany statements are identical (according to notepad++).